# return index of all factor variables that don't have a predefined name

Tags: r, data-cleaning, sapply

I'm trying to write a function that will return the index of all binary variables in a data frame with the exception of a predefined variable or list of variable supplied. you can generate example data with this:

```
data<-data.frame("RESPONSE" = sample(c("YES","NO"),100,replace = T),
             "FACTOR" = sample(c("YES","NO","MAYBE"),100,replace = T),
             "BINARY" = sample(c("YES","NO"),100,replace = T),
             "NUMERIC" = sample(1:100,100,replace = T))
```

In this case the predefined variable to ignore is "RESPONSE"

```
response.variable.name<-"RESPONSE"
```

I can get the list of all the binary variables using:

```
sapply(data,function(x) nlevels(as.factor(x))==2)
```

and the list of all variables not named "RESPONSE" using:

```
!names(data) %in% response.variable.name
```

but the output I'm looking for ignores the predefined column or list of columns and would return the same output as you would get with:

```
names(data)=="BINARY"
```

I thought using the two conditions inside the sapply function, but names(x) inside sapply returns NULL values. I know there's an easy fix for this problem

Comment: Do you need `sapply(data[setdiff(names(data), response.variable.name)],function(x) nlevels(as.factor(x))==2)`

Comment: I think you're just looking for `&`, like this? `sapply(data,function(x) nlevels(as.factor(x))==2) & !names(data) %in% response.variable.name`

Comment: It'd be pretty useful if you'd share the output you're looking for given that sample input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## Desired result?
names(data)=="BINARY"
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

## Desired method
response.variable.name<-"RESPONSE"
sapply(data,function(x) nlevels(as.factor(x))==2) & !names(data) %in% response.variable.name
# RESPONSE   FACTOR   BINARY  NUMERIC 
#    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE 
## same values, has names too (bonus!)
## wrap in `unname()` if you don't like names
```

Comment: That was really helpful. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map` from `base R`

```
unlist(Map(function(x, y) nlevels(factor(x)) == 2 &
       y != response.variable.name, data, names(data)))
#  RESPONSE   FACTOR   BINARY  NUMERIC 
#   FALSE    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE
```

---

Or using `imap`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
   imap_lgl(~ nlevels(.x) == 2 & .y != response.variable.name)
#  RESPONSE   FACTOR   BINARY  NUMERIC 
#   FALSE    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE
```